# Let Angular 2+ routing ignore unmatched paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Our application is a legacy application with old jQuery, Angular 1 and now Angular 2+. Rewriting old code in Angular 2 completely is not an option.

On the webpage, some portions are driven by Angular 1 routing, and now i have got Angular 2 to work on it with `HashLocationStrategy`.

However, while it is possible to access the new routes for the Angular 2 app, it throws errors on trying to load an Angular 1 route. The error is from the Angular 2 side. How does one make it ignore unmatched paths?

The error is:

> Cannot match any routes

Comment: did you read this doc about [Dividing routes between Angular and AngularJS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#dividing-routes-between-angular-and-angularjs) ?

Comment: that worked. thanks!